Snowpark - cxOracle - Cannot locate libcntlsh.so
Unable to connect to Oracle database using Snowpark Snowflake. Getting the below
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 32, in compute
  File "_udf_code.py", line 21, in wrapper
  File "_udf_code.py", line 19, in oracle_conn
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "@pythonlibrary/instanctclient_linux.zip/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

Code relevant
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="@pythonlibrary/instanctclient_linux.zip")
        with cx_Oracle.connect("user", "passwor", "dsn") as con:
            print("Database version:", con.version)
            print("Client version:", cx_Oracle.clientversion())
            cursor = con.cursor()
            result, = cursor.execute("select to_char(current_date) from dual")
            print("Today's date is:", repr(result))


i believe, you should use the unzipped version of the client
for example:
Path to oracle client on local machine
ora_client_config = {'orcl_client_path': '/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64'}
